# How to float right without affecting the vertical alignment of a inline-block?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a challenge, and would like to know the cleanest solution with the minimal effort custom side as I am using Bootstrap (and trying to solve without hardcoded values as I would like to use it as component with Angular...).

Below there is the code, but basically I have the problem on title. Two children, one is text and the other a div containing buttons which I would like to move to the right horizontally. Unfortunately, when I do that, then the text supposed to stay to the left is loosing the vertical alignment.

Here the code, where I would like to have Button in the middle:

```css
.pi-button-with-buttons{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-default pi-button-with-buttons">
    <span>Button</span> 
    <div> 
     <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 1</a> 
     <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 2</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to increase the line-height of the container, `2.375` seems to more or less get you there (for this specific example at least.) But I would rather recommend to not use floating and switch to flexbox here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `flex` like this :

```css
.pi-button-with-buttons{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px !important;
  display:flex!important;
  align-items:center;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons div {
  flex:1;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-default pi-button-with-buttons">
    <span>Button</span> 
    <div> 
     <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 1</a> 
     <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 2</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option** **1**: using `flexbox`

```css
.pi-button-with-buttons{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons span {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-default pi-button-with-buttons">
    <span>Button</span> 
    <div> 
     <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 1</a> 
     <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 2</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Option 2**: using `line-height`

```css
.pi-button-with-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons span {
  line-height: 36px;
}

.pi-button-with-buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-default pi-button-with-buttons">
  <span>Button</span>
  <div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Inside 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VXp Op: "Unfortunately, when I do that, then the text supposed to stay to the left is loosing the vertical alignment." -- the text on the left looks ok to me, what am I missing?

Comment: No need for `inline-flex`, take a look at Temani's answer about flexbox solution which is ok, can't be done with less code and the output is the most accurate, for second example I'd add `position: relative;` `top: -35px;` to the `.pi-button-with-buttons div` to make it work for the right ones, since `line-height` and `float` don't go well together.

Comment: @VXp Sure, that's all reasonable. The OPs question asks 'How to float right without affecting the vertical alignment of a inline-block?' Without additional information, I think my solution answers this fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately float: right loses the display: inline-block behaviour. Instead, remove the float: right and use flexbox on the wrapper, like so:

```
.btn-default {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: i think you have to use !important to be sure to override the display set by bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, I was basing the answer on the posted code, not used Bootstrap much. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: by the way it good to put a working code so the OP see the result ;)